# Производительность мобильных смартфонов, какая лучше?

Tags: производительность

Вот такой вопрос, какой телефон лучше покупать Двухядерный Qualcomm Snapdragon (1.2 ГГц) или одноядерный с частотою 1.5 Ггц или 1.8 Ггц?

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что он не относится к программированию или администрированию

Answer (score 1):

Лучше купить исходя из рейтинга производительности и цены телефона.

Есть ежедневно обновляемый обобщенный рейтинг производительности телефонов на Android [mobilebenchmark.net](http://www.mobilebenchmark.net/passmark_chart.html). Тест собирается программой [PassMark PerformanceTest Mobile](http://www.passmark.com/products/pt_mobile.htm).

Цены вы сами можете найти.

На сайте [mobilebenchmark.net](http://www.mobilebenchmark.net/popular_chart.html) так же есть отдельные тесты процессоров, памяти, дисков, 2D и 3D-производительности мобильных устройств.

Также можете посмотреть статью про сравнение мобильного двухъядерного процессора с одноядерными на [mobile-review.com](http://www.mobile-review.com/articles/2011/nvidia-tegra2.shtml). Представленные графики показывают преимущество двухъядерного решения.

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, что существенное значение будет играть количество и тип приложений, работающий в фоновом режиме. Если таковых практически нет - то можно купить и одноядерный